# Can I access the sms / call log with Intel XDK

Tags: html, intel-xdk

Does anyone perhaps have some code examples of accessing the phone's sms/call log using Intel XDK please?

I'm just after being able to see the MSISDN of the caller / sender that sends an SMS/Text to my device.

Ideally, code should work for any platform, but Android if nothing else is possible?

Comment: look at: https://github.com/dalyc/Cordova-CallLog-Plugin